# Allow user to type in answer and give available suggestions as user types in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In some applications and websites there are only a limited selection of options but too many to scroll through so the application or website will allow the user to begin typing their answer in a `Text_Field` and then show in a `Picker_View` the possible options based on what the user has typed in. Is there an easier way to do this rather than use an absurd amount of "if-then" statements to filter out each option?

Comment: This may help you https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many options you have to sort through, we have used both tableviews and actionsheets in my company. Actionsheets don't have a easy search and we only use them if we have less than ten options. But they provide a large data picker type selection. Tableviews are pretty easy to add searching into. I have used a lot of tutorials from raywenderlich.com. And I used [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) one to build my first searchable tableview.

Hope that helps. Happy coding!